# Regexp to mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

Need to construct regexp to this

2 1231 21231 2312 2123 22 2

Need to find only 2, not 1231, not 21231, only 2

So, my regexp is

```
^[[:digit:]]?{1}[2]{1}^[[:digit:]]?
```

Is it right ?

Sorry if my ask like a 'do it for me', but i really cannot into regexp.

**UPD**
input string 2 22 1312 123123 22312 21 2 
need to match "2" 
**2** 22 1312 123123 22312 21 **2** 
with or w\o digits after\before

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Is this meant to be one long string or multiple strings to be tested? Try to write it like `input: "12 34"` and `output: "2"`, possibly using some character to find that's not ambiguous.

Comment: input string
2 22 1312 123123 22312 21 2
need to match "2"
**2** 22 1312 123123 22312 21 **2**
with or w\o digits after\before

Comment: why are you using regexp in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds simple enough...

```
/\b2\b/g
```

How about this one? **[Example](http://regexr.com?30ko7)**

Comment: How could i use this in Mysql query? While selecting a column i hav e to select individual number like this, how could i achieve this? 
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `table_id` REGEXP /(/\b2\b/)/g;